# Outline of Generic Separable Banach Spaces don't have a Schauder Basis

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, descriptive-set-theory, baire-category, schauder-basis

So, I know P. Enflo showed that there is a separable Banach Space that doesn't satisfy the approximation property. My professor mentioned during class that in fact generic separable Banach Spaces don't have a Schauder basis where generic is in terms of Baire Category with some topology. I was hoping someone could outline how we put a topology on the space of all Banach Spaces in order to show dense $G_{\delta}$.

Also, an outline of how we show density since I assume we end up showing comeagerness of our set.

Comment: I see that this question was posted almost simultaneously to MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/220752/outline-of-generic-separable-banach-spaces-dont-have-a-schauder-basis Cross-posting is generally discouraged, but if you do post the same question on multiple sites, it is [advised to add link to other post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5088).

Comment: That does not change that I consider it interesting question and that I find it interesting. I upvoted it and I even considered putting a [bounty](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bounty) at some later point - if the question is still unanswered. I guess you can see that adding a bounty only to find out that the question is already answered on MO would not be the very effective way to do.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of protocol, but it seemed to generate very little interest on here, and I just discovered mathoverflow and thought it might do better there.